# Handle permission based on both person and role?

Tags: users, workflows

I am using workflow module for a publishing website.

There are many people who have the role reviewer....The comapny want to enable that when you change state from 'in moderation' to 'in-review', we can assign the content to a reviewer through an autocomplete field. NOT ALL reviewers.

Workflow content permissions does a great job, for making it role based. So the author is no longer allowed to edit the article when it is 'in-review' state. Now I don't want to allow all reviewers to edit it 'in-review', only the one that has been selected.

Is there a module for this? If not, how should I be going about this.

P.S. -: I am barely a few weeks into Drupal, so go easy :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first to use the [Rules module](https://drupal.org/project/rules) to fire an action on your workflow transition : from 'in moderation' to 'in-review'

Second try to use the [Node access user reference module](https://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) or the [Nodeaccess module](https://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) to use an API method inside your a custom PHP code or as a rule's action to grant the referenced user

Comment: I am already using the Rules module...What action could I fire when the state changes from 'in-transition' to 'in-review'?

Comment: a custom php code why not